# Is Java 1.6.0_26 the same as Java 1.6.26?

Tags: java-6

Well, that's embarrassing, but I really could not find the answer.

We started a new project, one of the requirements was to have JDK 1.6.26 installed. I downloaded `JDK 6 Update 26` after installing it and performing `java -version` I got that the version is 1.6.0_26.

Are these (JDK 1.6.0_26 & 1.6.26) the same thing? Or is this mistyped requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking JDK 1.6.26 doesn't exist. Commonly used names are "1.6.0_26" and "Java 6 Update 26" and "6u26".

But given that there's no 1.6.x release of the JDK where *x* is anything but `0`, I'm pretty sure that they meant Java 6 Update 26 (a.k.a 1.6.0_26).

Answer (score 2):

Just ask the person who gave you these requirements. 100% sure that you're right and it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitelly same thing. It's only name convention.